# Wpf - Xaml : Binding a list of TextBox in a List of String to Source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I want to create a list of TextBox in binding with `ObservableCollection<String>` in a ViewModel but i have a problem. The binding **performs only by source to dialog** but it **not works by dialog to source**

in my ViewModel i have

```
   private ObservableCollection<String> _ListSashDim;

    public ObservableCollection<String> ListSashDim
    {
        get { return _ListSashDim; }
        set {
            if (_ListSashDim != value)
            {
                _ListSashDim = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ListSashDim");
            }
        }

    }
```

the list is initialized as below

```
  private ObservableCollection<string> createListSashPosition(int numAnte)
    {
        ObservableCollection<string> ls = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numAnte; i++)
        {
            ls.Add("X");
        }

        return ls;
    }
```

in my Xaml i have a DataTemplate

```
 <!--#region DataTemplate ListSashDim-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateSashDim">
        <ItemsControl>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="116" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock FontSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Sash Dim"></TextBlock>
                <TextBox x:Name="tbSashDim" Width="90" Text="{Binding Path=.,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
    <!--#endregion-->
```

and an ItemsControl in a StackPanel

```
<StackPanel   
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                  Margin="0,10,0,0">

                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListSashDim, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                              Margin="0" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplateSashDim}" Padding="8" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></StackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
```

Thanks so much
Manuel

Comment: `Binding Path=.,Mode=TwoWay` will not magically replace a string in the source collection. You should have a collection of objects with a string property, e.g. like shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2872964/1136211. Besides that, your DataTemplateSashDim looks odd. Why is there a StackPanel as single item of an ItemControl? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks so much. I have **Resolved** using a collection of object with a property String property. The StackPanel in a single item of an ItemControl is an error of copy and past. Thanks so much. Manuel