# Can I use a List<T> and a List<Expression> to populate a wpf datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

Can I use a `List<T>` and a `List<Expression>` to populate a wpf datagrid?

```
  {
      var processes = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();
      PopulateDataGrid( processes, x => x.ProcessName, x => GetSafeFilename( x ) );  
  }
  private string GetSafeFilename( Process p )
  {
     try
     {
        return p.MainModule.FileName;
     }
     catch ( Exception )
     {
        return "";
     }
  }
```

The idea is that I want to be able to pass a list and params list of expressions to populate a datagrid.  I only want to show the list of expressions on the datagrid.

I'd also like to be able to get the underlying object for the selected row.

I know I can use anonymous types like:

```
var list = processes.Select( x => new {TagObject = x, ProcessName = x.ProcessName, Filename = GetSafeFilename( x )} ).ToList();
```

But then I have to make sure not to add "TagObject" to the datagrid.

Any ideas?  I realy like the idea of the syntax:

```
PopulateDataGrid( processes, x => x.ProcessName, x => GetSafeFilename( x ) );
```

But I'm not sure how to make it happen.

Comment: [How to bind a List<string> to a DataGridView control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479329/how-to-bind-a-liststring-to-a-datagridview-control)

Comment: [WPF: Bind DataGrid to List<String>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872916/wpf-bind-datagrid-to-liststring)

Comment: When you talk of expressions, you mean [lambda expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), right? Because WPF has its own [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer to this question. I'm not sure what I was thinking when I wrote the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to provide a set of expressions and use each expression to create its own colum in the grid. There is a major problem you'll have to resolve: DataGrid columns are resolved using data bindings to **properties** of the object:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="ProcessName" Binding="{Binding ProcessName}" />
```

so we can map a property-accessing expression to a DataGrid column with the appropriate binding. But your second column doesn't represent a property access, but rather a method call; and you can't set the binding of a datagridcolumn to a method call:

```
<!-- won't work -->
<DataGridTextColumn Header="GetSafeFilenamee" Binding="{Binding GetSafeFilename}" />
```

In this case, because the purpose of the method is to handle the possible exception on trying to access details on `MainModule`; we might be able to avoid the exception with a proprty access and using WPF's target fallback mechanism. But a general mechanism that would reach into the IL of any arbitrary method to figure out the relevant property access is almost certainly out of scope for what you want to do.

---

Instead of `PopulateDataGrid` taking multiple expressions, each with its own property access, I would suggest a single expression that contains multiple property accesses. I can think of two such expressions:

- an expression that returns some array

  ```
  PopulateDataGrid(processes, x => new [] { x.ProcessName, x.MainModule.FileName });
  ```
- or an expression that returns an anonymous type. This has the added benefit of allowing you to pass headers to the columns:

  ```
  PopulateDataGrid(processes, x => new { x.ProcessName, Path = x.MainModule.FileName });
  ```

Also, I would suggest exposing it as an extension method on DataGrid. The signature could look like this:

```
public static void PopulateDataGrid<TElement, TFieldsExpression>(this DataGrid dg, IEnumerable<TElement> itemsSource, Expression<Func<TElement, TFieldsExpression>> fieldsExpr) {
}
```

We need the `TFieldsExpression` generic parameter so the compiler can recognize the second parameter as an expression.

---

The first step is to parse the multi-expression into individual headers and property accesses. You could use something like the following:

```
private static List<(string name, Expression expr)> ParseFields<TElement, TFieldsExpression>(Expression<Func<TElement, TFieldsExpression>> fieldsExpression) {
    var body = fieldsExpression.Body;

    switch (body) {

        // an array initialization with elements
        // (as opposed to an array initialization with bounds -- new int[5])
        case NewArrayExpression newArrayExpr when body.NodeType == ExpressionType.NewArrayInit:
            return newArrayExpr.Expressions.Select(x => ("", x)).ToList();

        // anonymous type
        // the IsAnonymous extension method is included at the end of the post
        case NewExpression newExpr when newExpr.Type.IsAnonymous():
            return newExpr.Constructor.GetParameters().Select(x => x.Name).Zip(newExpr.Arguments).ToList();

        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Unhandled expression type.");
    }
}
```

Then you could write the following method:

```
public static void PopulateDataGrid<TElement, TFieldsExpression>(this DataGrid dg, IEnumerable<TElement> itemsSource, Expression<Func<TElement, TFieldsExpression>> fieldsExpr) {
    dg.ItemsSource = itemsSource;

    dg.Columns.Clear();

    var fields = ParseFields(fieldsExpr);
    foreach (var (name, expr) in fields) {
        if (expr is MemberAccessExpression mexpr) {
            dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn {
                Header = name,
                Binding = new Binding(mexpr.Member.Name)
            })
        } else {
            throw new ArgumentException("Unhandled expression type.");
        }
    }
}
```

You could then call this method as follows:

```
dg.PopulateDataGrid(list, x => new [] {x.ProcessName, x.HasExited, x.MachineName};
```

Note: most of this comes from [sample code](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreesInVBandCS/tree/master/CSharp_SetColumns) which accompanies an [MSDN article I've written about expression trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt833513?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The sample code handles additional expression types, long path chains (e.g. `x.MainModule.FileName`) and method calls to `String.Format`.

---

Helper extensions:

```
// using System.Reflection;

public static bool IsAnonymous(this Type type) =>
    type.HasAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() && type.Name.Contains("Anonymous") && type.Name.ContainsAny("<>", "VB$");

public static bool HasAttribute<TAttribute>(this MemberInfo mi, bool inherit = false) where TAttribute : Attribute =>
    mi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), inherit).Any();

public static bool ContainsAny(this string s, params string[] testStrings) =>
   testStrings.Any(x => s.Contains(x));
```