# Bind TextBoxes to List<>[i]

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

My object looks as the following :

```
public class Macro : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
        private string name = "";
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
            set
            {
                this.name = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<int> listParams = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        public ObservableCollection<int> ListParams
        {
            get { return this.listParams; }
            set
            {
                this.listParams = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("ListParams");
            }
        }

        public Macro()
        {

        }
        public Macro(string nom)
        {
            this.Name = nom;
        }

    }
```

in my XAML, I would like to create a list of `TextBoxes` Binding to ListParams[0],ListParams[1]... ListParams[20]. Is this possible to make such a binding? Until now I jsut created 20 "parameters"(int p0, int p1, int p2...) , but I am thinking on a way to make my object easier.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872916/wpf-bind-datagrid-to-liststring

Comment: Use an `ItemsControl` that binds to `ListParams`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an `ItemsControl` that binds to `ListParams` and put the `TextBox` in the `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListParams}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Since an `int` is immutable, you won't be able to change it using the `TextBox` though. If you want this, you should change the type of the source collection from `ObservableCollection<int>` to `ObservableCollection<YourClass>` where `YourClass` is a class with an `int` property that you then bind to:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=IntPropertyOfYourClass}" />
```

Comment: ok thanks, just was reading tutorials about ItemsControl, but I see you edited and posted an example, wll try it right now, thanks.

Comment: Finally I am having a doubt : I intended to make my object easier, but on the end making a special class just to store some ints has maybe no sense? Because then in all my code just `MyMacro.Pi` will become `MyMacro.ListParams[i].IntProperty`... seems I am making it just more complicated? Then also forgot this precision, that in front of my listboxes, I need to put some labels "a,b,c,d..." for each parameter

Comment: You are making it MVVM friendly. There is a reason why you should bind to a *view* model.

Comment: the only reason is each of my macros have a list of parameters (up to 20), and I want to make an interface to edit these parameters (but some macros that have only 4 parameters may have unused parameters in grey).

Comment: @Siegfried.V: Then you should use an `ItemsControl` and a custom model like `YourClass`.

Comment: ok thanks, will continue this way then, bit new for me, but good experience it will be :)